# Nginx headers not appearing with Ingress controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I'm having a problem where my NGINX headers are not showing when I connect to the ingress controller's IP. For example, let's say I have a HTTP header called "x-Header" setup in my NGINX config map. If I go to the ingress controller's IP I don't see the header, but when I go to the NGINX load balancer IP, I see the headers. Also when I go to the ingress IP, I get the correct cert, but the NGINX IP gives me a self signed cert.  I don't think I have the controller setup right.

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: staticip
  labels:
    app: exam
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.example.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  backend:
    serviceName: example-app
    servicePort: 80
```

Ingress node:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: exam-node
  labels:
    app: exam
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: example-app
    tier: backend
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

To create the NGINX controller I used the command `helm install stable/nginx-ingress --name nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true`

My nginx controller logs say this:

`2018-07-29 19:57:11.000 CDT
updating Ingress default/example-ingress status to [{12.346.151.45 }]`

It seems the nginx controller knows about ingress but ingress doesn't know about the controller. I am probably confused on how Ingress and NGINX work together.

Comment: I don't think `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name` will work with GKE IP addresses in NGINX ingress. That'll only work for GKE Ingress.

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google I removed that annotation. Should my DNS record point to the ingress resource or the nginx-ingress load balancer?  The host for my ingress resource says */*. I am not sure what that means.

Comment: The controller shouldn't be acting as a front end for requests. So long as the Nginx ingress IPs are working, your config is done properly. Your DNS should point to the Nginx-ingress.